# PERCENT_RANK() in BigQuery returns Resources exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to use PERCENT_RANK() over a large dataset, it gives me an error.

```
SELECT 
  a2_lngram, 
  a2_decade, 
  a2_totalfreq, 
  a2_totalbooks, 
  a2_freq, a2_bfreq, 
  a2_arf, 
  c_avgarf, 
  d_arf, 
  oi, 
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d_arf DESC) plarf 
FROM [trigram.trigrams8]
```

With a destination table and AllowLargeResults returns:

"Resources exceeded during query execution."

When I limit the results to few hundreds it runs fine.

JobID: otichyproject1:job_PpTpmMXYETUMiM_2scGgc997JVg
The dataset is public.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Well, I understand what it means, the question is, since this runs in Google Cloud, how exactly are the resources exceeded and how it can be helped. I think Felipe answered exactly that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected: The input for an analytic/window function needs to fit in one node for it to run successfully.

```
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY d_arf DESC) plarf
```

will only run if all the rows fit in one node. If they don't you'll see the "Resources exceeded during query execution" error.

There's a way to scale up with analytic functions: Partition your data.

```
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY d_arf DESC) plarf
```

... then the function can be run over multiple nodes, as long as each 'country' rows fit in one VM.

Not your case though - the fix I would do here is calculate the total on a separate subquery, join, and divide.

In summary, analytic functions are cool, but they have scalability issues on the size of each partition - luckily there are other ways to get the same results.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the explanation of the limitation of the analytic function and the suggested solution!

Comment: Felipe, I have just realized I need the same thing again, but with rank or row numbers, not percentages. This I only see how to do with an analytic function, not through a JOIN. Any ideas?

Comment: Partition regardless and use the max () of the previous partition + position in this one?

Comment: I am sorry, not getting this, could you please elaborate a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: Open a new question and I'll give it a try (as soon as I'm able to)